# How to customize links for breadcrumbs widget for Yii?

Tags: yii, breadcrumbs

How to customize links for breadcrumbs widget for Yii?

I can change the property `tagName`, but it for container. I want to change a tag for each links from `a` to `li`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's no setting/property value that you can specify for the default CBreadcrumbs widget class that will give you `<li>`. You can confirm this if you check out its [`run()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs#run-detail) method. In the source you can see this:

```
public function run(){
 // code

 foreach($this->links as $label=>$url)
 {
    if(is_string($label) || is_array($url))
        $links[]=CHtml::link($this->encodeLabel ? CHtml::encode($label) : $label, $url);
    else
        $links[]='<span>'.($this->encodeLabel ? CHtml::encode($url) : $url).'</span>';
 }
 // more code
}
```

So what you'll have to do is `extend` this class and specify your own `run` method, where you can use `<li>` or [`CHtml::tag('li',//other options)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#tag-detail) instead of the default [`CHtml::link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail).

**Edit:**

Although i would suggest enclosing the `<a>` for each link with a `<li>` (instead of replacing it):

```
$links[]='<li>'.CHtml::link($this->encodeLabel ? CHtml::encode($label) : $label, $url).'</li>';
```

Comment: i've made a small update, with a suggestion. don't hesitate to ask for clarifications, and let me know how this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with 'activeLinkTemplate' and 'inactiveLinkTemplate' properties:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs',
               array('tagName'=>'ul', 
                     'homeLink'=>'<li>'.CHtml::link('Home', array('/')).'</li>',
                     'activeLinkTemplate'=>'<li><a href="{url}">{label}</a></li>',
                     'inactiveLinkTemplate'=>'<li class="active">{label}</li>',
                     'htmlOptions'=> array('class'=>'breadcrumb'),
                     'separator'=>' / ',
                     'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
             ));
```

Or U can write 'homeLink'=>false. But in this case U'll have to set Home url every time with $this->breadcrumbs.